# DISABLE Products When timer RUNS out

Tags: magento2

How to disable product when the the timer runs out below is my phtml code is it possible please let me know

here my code am calling in phtml file

```
 <?php
    $myBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\AttributeCollection');
     
    // print current product data
        $currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct();
        echo $currentProduct->getStartTime() . '<br />';
        echo $currentProduct->getEndTime() . '<br />';  
        ?>
    
    
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    p {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 60px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $currentProduct->getEndTime(); ?>").getTime();
    
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    
      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date("<?php echo $currentProduct->getStartTime(); ?>").getTime();
        
      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;
        
      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        
      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace blow section in your code :-

```
// If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        jQuery("#demo").hide();
        jQuery("#demo").after( "<p>EXPIRED</p>" );
      }
```

Comment: what exactly will thsi code does chirag?\

Comment: You need to find above section in your code and replace with my code. it will hide "<p id="demo"></p>" and add new p tag with your desired text. I think this is you want to achieve in your task.

Comment: no i want to hide the current product when timer runs out

Comment: and ur trying to hide <p> tag here

Comment: then replace "#demo" with your your div id in above code. You need to inspect the section you want to hide and replace in place of "#demo" in above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set current running time in `var now`. Replace this below code :

Replace this line : `var now = new Date().getTime();`

```
<?php
    $myBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\AttributeCollection');
     
    // print current product data
        $currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct();
        echo $currentProduct->getStartTime() . '<br />';
        echo $currentProduct->getEndTime() . '<br />';  
        ?>
    
    
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    p {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 60px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $currentProduct->getEndTime(); ?>").getTime();
    
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    
      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();
        
      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;
        
      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        
      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        jQuery('#product-addtocart-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: rohan check the updated question

Comment: i want to disable product when timer runs out

Comment: It's quite simple. You can add this line before Expire code line : jQuery('#product-addtocart-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: this will disable add to cart but i want to hide product